# Edittext null value validation in android

Tags: android

Hello i want validation in my login screen. i have two edittext when some one null of them than code show error like please enter username and password on login button click.

this is my first class activity_login.java

```
package com.ad_blinds.ad_bliends.ad_bliends;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by jignesh on 20-07-2016.
 */
public class activity_login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String USER_NAME ="";
    public static final String PASSWORD="";
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.techonlab.com/AdMobileApp/login.php";

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    private Button buttonLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);

        buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    private void login() {

        String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        userLogin(username, password);

    }

    private void userLogin(String username, String password) {
        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(activity_login.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                String jsonValue=s;

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonReplay = new JSONObject(jsonValue);
                    JSONObject userDetail = jsonReplay.getJSONObject("user_details");

                    String USER_ID = userDetail.getString("user_id");
                    String USER_NAME = userDetail.getString("user_name");
                    String SUCCESS = userDetail.getString("Success");

                    if(SUCCESS=="1")
                    {
                        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login",0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
                        Ed.putString("USER_ID",USER_ID);
                        Ed.putString("USER_NAME",USER_NAME);
                        Ed.putString("LOGIN",SUCCESS);
                        Ed.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(activity_login.this, "Wel-come "+USER_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity_login.this,activity_home.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username", params[0]);
                data.put("password", params[1]);

                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL, data);
                return result;
            }

        }
        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(username,password);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonLogin) {
            login();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my second class name is regsteruserclass.java

```
package com.ad_blinds.ad_bliends.ad_bliends;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 8/6/2015.
 */
public class RegisterUserClass {

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

              response = br.readLine();
            }
            else {
                response="Error";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to below to show validation:

```
private void login() {

    String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

   if (username.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter username",             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (password.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
    userLogin(username, password);
 }

}
```